# Espresso dependencies added in normal and test compilations

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I need to develop the instrumentations test for my android app, and also I need to implement the interface IdlingResource to my app in order to tell Espresso that the activity is idle; so I have to add the Espresso dependencies two times, one in the normal compile and one in the test compile, looks like that:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    [...]
    compile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    //    The following lib is already imported in a standard way, but needs to be imported again
    //    in the test environment.
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    [...]
}
```

But doing the normal compilation of the app doesn't work:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: [...]/app/build/intermediates/symbols/androidTest/debug/R.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Remove from your `build.gradle`:

```
compile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

See [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample/app/build.gradle#L47), You need to add `compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2'` instead of whole Espresso-core lib.